# Request ajax acessando scripts já incluidos

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Eae galera,

Tenho uma view que renderiza uma partial view.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    <div class="tab-control" data-role="tab-control">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="active">@Ajax.ActionLink(Resources.Base.Entry, "_List", "Entrada", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "_Content", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "Div_Loading" })</li>
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(Resources.Base.Data, "_Edit", "Entrada", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "_Content", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "Div_Loading" }, new { id = "Dados" })</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="frames" id="_Content">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("_List");}
        </div>
    </div>
```

**_List.cshtml**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("@Url.Action("_Grid", "Data")", function (data) {
        $('#con').replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

Essa view eu faço o include do jQuery nela porém na partial view com esse código acima ele fala que o jQuery não existe. Se eu incluo novamente o jquery em cima do código citado acima ele funciona normal.

Existe uma forma de fazer todas as minhas requisições ajax após o load da página terem acesso aos scripts incluídos?

Todos eles estão sendo carregados no final da página (antes do "<\body>")

Vlw!

Off: Notei que existe algumas perguntas no Stackoverflow que vale reputação, como posso fazer uma pergunta deste tipo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cigano obrigado pela ajuda.

Resolvi o problema colocando os scripts no head em vez de colocar antes do fechamento da tag **body**.

Como já li em várias pesquisas e benchmarks ao colocar os scripts no fim da página os scripts carregam em paralelo, que de nada adianta se você precisar fazer gambiarras para ter acesso a scripts ou ficar carregando novamente em requisições ajax.

Se o sistema tiver uso significativo de ajax recomendo carregar sempre os scripts no topo da página, caso contrário carregue antes do fechamento de body assim a parte visual da página é exibida mais rapidamente mesmo que os scritps ainda não tenham sido carregados.

Existem diversas técnicas para melhorar a performance e tempo de loading, dentre elas cache, minification, bundles, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Em ASP.NET MVC, **Scripts não devem ser colocados em Partial Views** pelo simples fato de que as Partial Views podem ser reaproveitadas em várias partes do seu código, provocando um comportamento estranho dos Scripts.

O correto é colocar seus scripts na `@session scripts` da sua `Index.cshtml`:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("@Url.Action("_Grid", "Data")", function (data) {
                $('#con').replaceWith(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Na View `Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, deve ter a seguinte declaração:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

É nela que será renderizado o conteúdo de `@section scripts`.

Comment: E onde devo chamar essa @section scripts?

Comment: @Trxplz0 Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: No caso quando eu fizer a requisição ajax isso vai funcionar? Eu faço o load da página /controller/action ele me carrega esse index.cshtml que faz o render do _List.cshtml. A partir dai todos os links dentro de _List.cshtml carrega via ajax dando replace no conteúdo da propria div #con, que se encontra no _List.cshtml.

Comment: Se o método do `Controller` devolver uma *Partial View* como a resposta sugere, sim.

Comment: Vlw pela resposta vou testar. Como ia colocar o @RenderSection na Layout.cshtml pra mim não ia funcionar já que as PartialViews não faz o uso do Layout Master.

Comment: Yep, não funciona assim não, pq as partial views não fazem o uso do Layout.cshtml(master) que tem o RenderSection. O jeito é fazer como fazia-se na epoca em que ajax virou febre. Interceptar os scripts de requisições ajax e interpretar manualmente. Vlw mesmo pela ajuda de qualquer forma!